# iOS Location updates stop after 15-30 minutes

Tags: swiftui

I've built an app in SwiftUI, and have followed all the instructions I can to register the CLocationManager, and allow it to background.  However, after some time in the background, my app stops producing location updates.  When I view the file containing the coordinates, I have data for 15-30 minutes, then nothing.  Snippets of the location manager init:

```
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.activityType = .fitness
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 0;
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let newLocation = locations.last!
        session.addPointToCurrentSegment(newLocation)
        coreDataHelper.add(toCoreData: newWayPoint)
    }
```

My app has full permissions granted to access location "Always allow"

Comment: Is the app, by chance, going into the background?

Comment: @yrb - Yes, it definitely goes to the background.  But nothing I've tried allows updates to continue while backgrounded.

Comment: That is normal operation. See this document: [Handling Location Events in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background)

Comment: Thank you! Does this indicate that location updates get resumed when brought back from background automatically (this is what I'm witnessing), but additionally I need to write code to receive the updates that are "pending" and were collected while the app was in background?

Comment: Read the documents and google it. There will be no "pending" updates. Location updates simply shut down unless you use Significant Location Changes(SLC) in the background it is not extremely accurate. It is more geared to geofencing so you can get notice when you arrived somewhere, think like 500 to 1000 meter accuracy. And it could be greater in more rural areas.

Comment: I've put quite a bit of time into googling this already - how do activity tracking apps do it? I've used plenty of apps that work flawlessly.  Are they preventing backgrounding altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the info posted in the other answers is correct! The issue turned out to be the Swift prohibition of a continuously running timer in the app.  This ended up blocking the thread or something, which was cutting out the location tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't handling the location update anywhere when location manager does update. It should update in the background if “Location updates” is set in capabilities.

```swift
class Location: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var location: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    private var manager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    func requestAuthorization() {
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        /*
         request authorization here
         */
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        /*
         handle authorization changes here
         */
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // get the most recent location
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.location = location
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
       if let error = error as? CLError, error.code == .denied {
          manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
          return
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do have that handler, just edited out part of it for brevity, I updated my question to show where I'm pulling in the newLocation

Answer (score 0):

I wrote your own code, but it worked for me. The only different things I did were:

1. locationManager.activityType = .other
2. Use all methods of the delegate
3. In one of the methods of the delegate (didPause) try to start again, setting the manager again (locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false and locationManager.activityType = .other)

4)start the notification of awakening for the change of position, again in the didPause method.

5. I did not use the locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation and locationManager.distanceFilter = 0

for point 4 I recommend this reading:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unlocationnotificationtrigger